# Translate shorthand

Tags: html, css

Can someone please clarify what the shorthand for translate is.

```
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) ;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%); 
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

How do I condense this?

Answer (score 1):

You just put them all in a line. (not unlike border)

`border: 1px solid blue;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

```
/* Multiple function values */

transform: translateX(10px) rotate(10deg) translateY(5px);
```

hopefully you can use autoprefixer to spit out the -prefixes-

Toss it in a CodePen and turn on autoprefixer to check it out - then look at the compiled styles.